# How to interpret those ACF & PACF?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, acf-pacf, differencing

I have some problems when analyzing my time series dataset.

Basically, the dataset is about the daily sales volume of an FMCG company (they work from Monday to Saturday with Sunday being a day off, so the sales volume of Sunday will not be listed in the dataset).

When plotting the ACF of the dataset, I noticed some unusually significant correlations in lag 6, 12, 18, and so on, which is a multiplication of 6. My first conclusion is that maybe due to the working day of the week being 6, the dataset exhibits a seasonal pattern.
[image]

When differencing the dataset with the number of lags is 6, seems like all the lag at multiplication of 6 lies within the significant limit. Nevertheless, there still be a high correlation in lag 6.

How can I continue to interpret that plot? This is my first post so if there are any problems with the post, please let me know.

Note:

- The dataset before differences is not stationary (ADF test), and after differences it is stationary.
- I also include PACF of the dataset before and after differences.

Updated:

- My dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TflroZYKcykHyP_GHMZgchGGEFxvuZidKLZ_O26ghTA/edit#gid=742724586

Comment: Both the ACF and the PACF indicate that you differenced (at lag 6) a time series that was not integrated (at lag 6) in the first place, so you are suffering the consequences of *overdifferencing*. That is a common mistake; you should not have differenced the time series.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your response. I have some more questions related to the topic. 
- Instead of differencing the time series, how can I make my dataset stationary? Because the ADF test suggests that my dataset is not stationary.
- If I want to forecast with that dataset, may I try to stationaries the dataset or use some kind of forecasting technique that does not require stationary time series?
- Is my conclusion about the existence of seasonal based on the ACF is reasonable, or the correlation simply because of some irregular patterns in the dataset?

Thank you, have a great day!

Comment: You might be misinterpreting the results of the ADF test, as the ACF graph clearly shows there is no unit root in the original data. To account for the seasonality at lag 6, try a regression with a dummy variable or a SARIMA$(p,0,q)\times(P,0,Q)_6$ model.